# Xcode 11 crashing on iPhone 13.1 app running

Tags: xcode, ios13

I updated Xcode today (Xcode 11.0), and now it crashes every time I try running any project on my iPhone (iOS 13.1).

Already tried:

- Cleaning derived data
- Cleaning library cache folder
- Uninstalling xCode and downloading it again from the store
- Restarting Mac
- Restarting iPhone
- Reconnecting iPhone trough itunes

The odd thing is that the Xcode activity doesn't show the "installing app" phase, it goes straight to "Running app on device" and then crashes. Running on the simulator works without a problem.

Already searched on the Apple forums and sent the report to Apple, but maybe there is something I can do to solve te issue.

Error log:

```
Process:               Xcode [873]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.0 (14936)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-14936000000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832762837
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [873]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2019-09-25 11:47:10.497 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G95)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX


Time Awake Since Boot: 550 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        16  Dispatch queue: Mutex to protect _hasPerformedWorkerAction

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
com.apple.main-thread
ProductBuildVersion: 11A420a
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Calling block provided to DVTSyncPerformBlock() here:

  0   DVTSyncPerformBlock (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[IDEExecutionRunnableTracker executionWantsHold:withError:] (in IDEFoundation)
  2   -[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_3 (in IDEFoundation)
  4   __48-[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
  8   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 11   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 12   __DVTDispatchAfter_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 13   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15   _dispatch_source_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 20   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 21   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
...
...
...
    0x7fff63005000 -     0x7fff6300affb  libunwind.dylib (35.4) <24A97A67-F017-3CFC-B0D0-6BD0224B1336> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff6300b000 -     0x7fff6303afff  libxpc.dylib (1336.261.2) <7DEE2300-6D8E-3C00-9C63-E3E80D56B0C4> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 430
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 21

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.1G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.1G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.2G(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               640K        5 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 1160K        2 
CG image                          1296K       95 
CG raster data                      56K        6 
CoreAnimation                     25.8M      164 
CoreGraphics                         8K        1 
CoreImage                          776K       81 
CoreUI image data                 3000K       34 
CoreUI image file                  688K       14 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        1 
Foundation                         344K        5 
Image IO                            80K        5 
JS JIT generated code              1.0G        3 
Kernel Alloc Once                 1036K        2 
MALLOC                           136.4M      116 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       10 
Memory Tag 242                      12K        1 
Memory Tag 251                      64K        3 
Performance tool data             8208K        1         not counted in TOTAL below
SQLite page cache                  128K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       23 
Stack                             19.2M       23 
VM_ALLOCATE                        360K       24 
WebKit Malloc                     1144K        3 
__DATA                            94.4M      755 
__DATA_CONST                         8K        1 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       357.4M      236 
__TEXT                           723.4M      680 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
libnetwork                        1152K        4 
mapped file                      169.2M      230 
shared memory                      676K       15 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.6G     2547 

Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM 186.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2,9 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: kHW_IntelIris6100Item, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54424C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54424C41522D4E5544
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500,28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: iPhone
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: Does Xcode 11.0 support iOS 13.1? You may need to install Xcode 11.1 to run your apps on an iPhone running iOS 13.1.

Comment: Yes, you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes) `Xcode 11 supports development for devices running iOS 13.1`

Comment: I had a crash like this. My solution was adding the new BT background Privacy string to the app plist file.

Comment: Facing the same problem. My Xcode is 11 and I have tried to run it on iPhone XS(iOS 14.0.1). I have added Device Support(https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport) before running the app. But it doesn't work. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So, I found that inside this folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport
```

Xcode creates cache folders for all the physical devices symbols it paired.

This folder remains even if you uninstall Xcode, and the cache is reused even when you install other versions of the software.

Deleting the folders content made Xcode download the symbols again, run `prepare debug support for the device` phase and reset the device connection, solving the problem.

Comment: My XS froze at every debug app launch. Re-downloading the debug support files helped. Thanks!

Comment: iOS DeviceSupport was just a broken alias for me... it pointed to nowhere. Not sure how that happened, but deleting it fixed the issue for me. Now there is a proper folder there with the caches you mentioned.

Comment: Just so it's stated: if you try opening Simulator right away after deleting the folder, it won't load. You need to open Xcode first to get the download prompt.

Comment: You save my time +1

Comment: @alxlives I can't seem to find that folder

Answer (score 4):

According to @alxlives 'Deleting the folders content made Xcode download the symbols again, run prepare debug support for the device phase and reset the device connection, solving the problem.' This solution solved the problem for me. Here is a terminal command to remove all contents inside of the folder.

```
rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/
```

This commands remove all files that are located inside of the Device Support folderl.

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to Project Folder
[image]

2.Right-click on xcodeproj 
[image]

3.Click Show package Content
[image]

4.Delete xcuserdata directory
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue with Xcode 11.1 and an iPhone XR running iOS 13.2.3 (iPad running that OS version was fine). The accepted answer didn't work for me. Upgrading to Xcode 11.2.1 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same crash on XCode 11.3 . I went on to "Show package contents" (right click on) of the `".xcworkspace"` workspace directory and deleted `"xcuserdata"` folder. This resolved the crash for me.