# Xcode 11.2.1 quits unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

Xcode quits unexpectedly when I connect my iphone 7plus and open `devices and simulators`. I want to test my app on physical iphone.
app is working fine on the simulator and if I open `devices and simulators` without connecting my iphone then nothing happens.
I don't know why this thing is happening. Should I try to update `MacOs` and `xcode`?
please help!

xcode v11.2.1,
macOs Catalina v10.15.1,
iphone 7plus ios v14.2

Error details-

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11B500
Crashing on exception: The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window.
```

can anyone tell me what this really means?

Comment: I don't know why it crashes (that seems a little extreme), but Xcode 11.2.1 absolutely cannot deal with a phone that is running iOS 14.2, so even if it didn't crash, what you're doing would be totally pointless. So yes, obviously, update Catalina to 10.5.7 and then update Xcode to 12.2.

Comment: Besides incompatibility, this problem was fairly common with XCode 11 (have not seen it with XCode 12 yet). Typically this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58117854/5318223

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 11 crashing on iPhone 13.1 app running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101444/xcode-11-crashing-on-iphone-13-1-app-running)

Comment: no @KirilS., I will  try updating the macos and the xcode.

Comment: found the issue here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659608

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried everything to resolve this issue but the problem solved with updating the operating system and the xcode.